# How to change or add dark theme to CodeBlocks?

Tags: themes, codeblocks, darkmode

I have just installed Codeblocks in my Windows.
When I launch the application the background of the screen where we write the code is white.
I would prefer black or any other color.
I am not sure whether we can change the color/theme OR add more themes.

Answer (score 7):

First, you need to download some syntax color schemes, so I recommend you to download this file: [colour_themes.conf](https://gist.github.com/yzhong52/6852140faa233408de67). Then you will have to install it. Follow these steps:

- Close the program Code::Blocks.
- Run the program `cb_sharing_config.exe` (for Windows users, so it's your case). For Linux or Mac users, run the command `cb_share_config` from the terminal.
- This program UI has 2 columns. In the left column, you have to load the downloaded file: `colour_themes.conf`. In the right column, you have to indicate the file `default.conf` (it will find the path automatically).
- Select the themes you want to import to Code::Blocks. Then, click `Transfer` to transfer them to the file `default.conf`. Finally click `Save`. You probably want to select them all to use them later.

Now, the color schemes are installed, so it's time to select a new one:

- Open the program Code::Blocks.
- Go to the menu: `Settings` > `Editor` and select the tab `Syntax highlighting`.
- You will see a select box with the label `colour theme`; select one.

Comment: Where do I download the .conf file to? Do I download it to the same place the codeblocks.exe is?

Comment: Also I believe it is cb_share_config.exe for windows, at least for me.

Comment: I tried using your color scheme .conf file and it isn't working for me. I don't see any other color themes that I can choose other than the default one. I am using the latest nightly build of Code:Blocks on Windows 10. Do you have another alternative .conf file for me to use?

Comment: I used this color scheme and it worked though. There might be a problem with your recommended link. Is there a way to change the theme for more than the text editor? I would like the rest of the window to have a different theme.

https://gist.github.com/reymon359/cb8106eae1ecb2fd4da63f3c1206e2bd

Comment: I used the 'vim' theme of the above github .conf file, but I cannot see my text cursor when clicking on the code. Is there a way to change the color of the text cursor so that I can see it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Follow [this tutorial](https://sangams.com.np/installing-codeblocks-dark-themes/). It will only change the code editor area though, not the menus and toolbars.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Go to this site https://gist.github.com/yzhong52/6852140faa233408de67.
Download the file as zip, extract and copy out the `colour_themes.config` file.
Close CodeBlocks.
Open CodeBlocks Share Config on the machine.
Click `Source configuration file` `...` and select the downloaded `colour_themes.config` file.
Click `Destination configuration file` `...` > Local Disk > Users > Your PC Name > AppData > Roaming > CodeBlocks > Choose `default.conf`.
Meanwhile set your file explorer to show hidden items so as to show AppData folder.
Mark/check all the boxes showing under the `Source configuration file`.
Then click `Transfer >>`.
Click `Save`.
Open CodeBlock, go to `Settings` > `Editor...` > `Syntax highlighting`.
Select `default` > click `OK`.
Now open your code.
You will notice you can't see your cursor, let's fix that.
`Settings` > `Editor...` > `Margins and caret`.
Click `Colour`, change it to white, click `OK`.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).