# Can't see my text cursor in Code::Blocks when changing text editor to dark theme

Tags: c++, windows, configuration, windows-10, codeblocks

When I followed the instructions on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69215838/13600624) to change my theme in [this .conf file](https://gist.github.com/reymon359/cb8106eae1ecb2fd4da63f3c1206e2bd) to the "vim" theme, it worked properly, but I was not able to see my text cursor because both the cursor and the screen is black. Is there a way to fix this or change the cursor color on Code::Blocks?

I tried turning on the text cursor indicator in Settings but for some reason it works well on every application except Code::Blocks.

Is there a way to make the whole Code::Blocks window the same theme as the editor or is only the editor theme configurable?

I am on Windows 10 and I am using the 30 July 2023 nightly build of Code::Blocks. Thanks for helping.

Comment: q.v. https://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=7882.0

Comment: Thanks @Elijay. Does anyone know how to make the whole Code::Blocks window have a dark theme?

Comment: Not sure.  I suspect you either need to either make your own dark theme, or see if someone has shared their own dark theme creation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to @Elijay's comment, I now know the setting to change the cursor color is at `Settings -> Editor -> Margins and Caret.` Thanks!